# "the single most valuable account"

Tags: expressions

I'd like to apply for something where I have to indicate my personal wealth. My assets are distributed among 20 different financial institutions. I don't want to send in bank statements for each of them. How can I state that I just present the one bank account that has the highest value, without explaining it as complicated as I just did here? Would

> Please find attached a bank statement of the single most valuable account

be understandable and grammatically correct?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think "single" is unnecessary, as you're already speaking about *the* most valuable account. And "attach" should be "attached".

Comment: if you are required to declare your total wealth, then the amount in the single largest account would be an under-declaration. In my country there are various services and benefits where, to qualify, total wealth must be declared, e.g. government benefits reduce if you have more than a certain sum in savings. and doing what you suggest would be classed as fraud. Of course that may not relevant to your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much. "Attach" was actually just a typo. Apologies... Thank you, @Joachim. Thanks, Michael Harvey for pointing this out. It is not relevant to my situation, but well worth mentioning!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be likely to lead to answers about the desirability of doing this as opposed to anything which might help English language learners.

Comment: @mdewey. That's not the OP's fault. The OP asked a clear, concise and well-descibed question about how to word a fairly complicated concept in a few words. Their question shouldn't be closed because of the people giving answers going off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is understandable, but probably not what a native speaker would say.  I would say

> Please find attached a statement for **the account with the highest balance**.

*Valuable* doesn't exactly work here, because it means something like "worth a great deal of money", but your account isn't exactly *worth* a lot of money, it just *is* a lot of money.  You would say that a jewel or an artwork is valuable, but not an account.

*Balance* means "the amount of money in an account", so "with the highest balance" is a good way to say "with the most money in it".

As an aside, it should be **find attached**, not *find attach*, because *attached* is a participle that can work like an adjective (the statement *is attached*), but *attach* by itself is just a bare infinitive and can't be used like an adjective.